# Django 1.10 full text search across multiple fields. How to get distinct records?

Tags: django, postgresql, full-text-search

Given these models:

```
class Listing(models.Model):
  features = models.ManyToManyField('Feature', related_name='listing_details')
  comments = models.TextField()

class Feature(models.Model):
  feature = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
```

How do I do a full-text search for `Listing`s with text in either comments or one of the related `Feature`s?

I tried this:

```
In[28]: Listing.objects.annotate(search=SearchVector('comments', 'features__feature')).filter(search='something').count()
Out[28]: 
1215
```

So, I know not all those records contain the text `something`.

However, the number is "right" in the sense that a regular non-full-text query comes up with the same number:

```
In[33]: Listing.objects.filter(Q(comments__icontains='something') | Q(features__feature__icontains='something')).count()
Out[33]: 
1215
```

I can get down to just the `Listing` objects containing the text `something` in the `comments` field or in `features__feature` like so:

```
In[34]: Listing.objects.filter(Q(comments__icontains='something') | Q(features__feature__icontains='something')).distinct().count()
Out[34]: 
25
```

The real question boils down to how do I get those same 25 records back with full text search?

Comment: Did you find a solution? The only solution I see is to either do the SQL by hand or use 3 queries, one to get the ids of the search, the second one to filter out this list of ids on the 'distinct' field you need, and the third one to redo the search (if you need to rank the results) using the unique ids.

Comment: No, I gave up on it and plan to revisit the problem again in the future.

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: No. I never got back around to looking at it more.

Answer (score 10):

I used [ManyToManyField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField) in [SearchVector](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/postgres/search/#searchvector) with [StringAgg](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/postgres/aggregates/#stringagg) to avoid strange duplication and have correct results.

In your example the correct query should be:

```
from django.contrib.postgres.aggregates import StringAgg
from django.contrib.postgres.search import SearchVector

Listing.objects.annotate(
    search=SearchVector('comments') + SearchVector(StringAgg('features__feature', delimiter=' '))
).filter(search='something')
```

Comment: Will it work with SearchRank? And how to use it?